# MLE classifier of Gaussians

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

#### Setup

There are two Gaussians $G_1,G_0$ with parameters $(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $(\mu_0,\sigma_0^2)$ respectively, and $\mu_1>\mu_0$, $\sigma_1 > \sigma_0$.

I am classifying draws $x$ from the Gaussians according to maximum likelihood. I think that means for a given $x$, I classify it as coming from $G_1$ if

$$\frac{N(x\vert\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)}{N(x\vert\mu_0,\sigma_0^2)} >1$$ and from $G_0$ otherwise.

Seems to me that is equivalent to

$$ \iff N(x\vert\mu_1,\sigma_1^2) > N(x\vert\mu_0,\sigma_0^2)$$

$$ \iff N(x\vert\mu_1,\sigma_1^2) - N(x\vert\mu_0,\sigma_0^2) > 0$$

#### Issue

Here's where I'm starting to get nervous:

The above seems like a difference of iid normal distributions, so might be there's a way to express the difference as a normal distribution itself -- something like

$$\iff N(x\vert\mu_1 -\mu_0,\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_0^2) \geq 0.$$

But it's a probability distribution, so it's always $\geq 0$, which doesn't make for much of a classifier. So I must be missing something here. Where have I gone wrong and how can I recover? Is there no way to express this as a simple distribution with a threshold value?

#### Update

Logging and simplifying produces a solution -- but I'll admit the calculation nevertheless seems fairly involved. Is this the simplest it gets? Here are calculations from `sympy`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference of two normally distributed random variables is also normally distributed, with parameters depending on mean and covariance. In your case you are directly comparing *densities* which is different. In other words:

$$N(x|\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)-N(x|\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma_1^2}}e^{-(x-\mu_1)^2/2\sigma_1^2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma_2^2}}e^{-(x-\mu_2)^2/2\sigma_2^2},$$

which does not need to be positive as it is not a density function (for starters its integral is 0). $N(x|\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ is NOT a random variable.

So if you were drawing $X_1,X_2$ from normal distributions $N_1,N_2$, their difference $X_1-X_2$ is normally distributed. Whereas you are comparing the values of densities at the same point $x$.

Also, I strongly recommend looking at the logorithm of your ratio and simplifying it, to avoid numerical imprecision which can happen when $x$ is far from both distributions, or when the denominator is small.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite helpful. I've updated my question after working on this. I'd be interested in your thoughts if you get a chance.

Comment: @Hatshepsut  I think you're better off simplifying by hand, because the above computerized solution suggests that there might be a singularity if $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$ which is false. It's really not so bad:

$$-(x-\mu_1)^2/2\sigma_1^2+(x-\mu_2)^2/2\sigma_2^2+\log(\sigma_2/\sigma_1)$$